# understanding jquery className manipulation

Tags: jquery

I have a form with lots of classes used. The format of classes are "hide-user-name, show-user-name, update-user-select, data-user-types". In one js file it is iterating through the classnames and doing some manipulations. I am not able to understand that properly.. Can somebody please help me understand what it is doing.

```
$.each(classNames, function(i, className) {
    className = className.split('-');
    var action = className.shift();
    alert("action "+action); --- Gives hide/show/update/data
    alert('.' + className.join('-'));--- .user-name
    if (action === 'show' || action === 'hide') {
      form.find('.' + className.join('-'))[action]();  
    }
});
```

I am not understanding the last line. What does this line do?

Update 2

```
var field = $(this), classNames = [], optionClassNames = [], updateField, dataField, options = [];

if (action === 'update') {
  className = className.join('-');
  updateField = form.find('input.' + className + ', select.' + className + ', textarea.' + className);

  if (dataField && dataField.length) {
    updateField.html('');
    options.length = 0;

$.each(dataField, function(x, item) {
  if (typeof item === 'object') {
    options.push('<option class="' + (item.condition || '') + '" value="' + item.value + '">' + (item.title || item.value) + '</option>');
  } else {
      options.push('<option class="' + (item || '') + '" value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
  }
});

updateField.html(options.join(''));

if (updateField.selectmenu) {
  updateField
    .selectmenu('destroy')
    .selectmenu({
      style:'dropdown',
      maxHeight: 200,
      transferClasses: true
    });
}

clearMessages(updateField);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the line `form.find('.' + className.join('-'))[action]();`

If will find out a descendant of the `form` element with class `user-name` then call the either `show()` or `hide` on that element

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tD2KP/)

Comment: Thanks Arun..I understood ..I have updated my question with another code snippet. It would be great if u can help me understand that as well?